# Black answers to Grand Prix attack

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense

I am reading about the Grand Prix Attack and the main lines of development for Black. One line considered is as follows.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nc3 d6 3. f4 g6 4. Nf3 Bg7 5. Bc4 Nc6 6. O-O
```

After White castling, I read, Black's best moves are Nf6 or Ne7 after e6.

As a beginner I want to ask, due to the fact that the idea behind the Grand Prix Attack is to attack Black's kingside, is queenside castling a line to consider for Black?

Comment: Don't forget that one of Black's main idea is to attack on the queenside, which could be problematic with a Black king on b8 or c8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I play it to avoid 'normal' sicilian lines.

When possible I do attack often on the Kside.

OTOH your example line is not one that gives me a lot of problems.
What causes me more problems as white is fighting for an early d5 by black and attacking on the Q side.

Yes some opponents have castled Qside as black which led to other type of play than a Kside attack by white.